# Bootstrap 3 Carousel: set unidirectional (vertical) transition

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am working on a Bootstrap 3 carousel with a *vertical transition* (and no arrows). It works, but I am looking for a particular transition.

```css
.carousel.vertical {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item {
  width: auto;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item {
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item.active {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next {
  top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev {
  top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev.right {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.left {
  top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.right {
  top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url("https://grgs.ro/1/i/sprite.png") no-repeat -528px -502px;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-position: -528px -524px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=west" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7p4kuox/3/)** with it too.

I want the carousel transition *direction* to be *upwards*, regardless of the succession of the indicators clicked.

In other words: if the active indicator (and the corresponding slide) is the third one and the user clicks the second or first one, the transition direction should be upwards, just as if the active indicator was the first and she/he was clicking the second or third indicator.

What is missing?

Comment: You want all the transitions to happen from bottom to top ? like slide to upward ?

Comment: @Towkir Yes, *that* is what I want.

Comment: what you did is fully css dependant, I mean if you put another carousel item, does it work without updating the CSS ? 
if you already know it, is it okay with you ?
or, If it can be implemented with the help of *actual* BS carousel, where the build in JS handles all of the tasks, would it help ?

Comment: @Towkir The default Bootstrap carousel transition is horizontal and it relies havelly on CSS. The aditions I have made for vertical transition also relies on CSS. I don't know if additional JavaScript is necessary to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I did a lot of search regarding this issue, Found a lot of SO questions where no one could provide the required solution.
But I found one.

Here is the snippet, hope this helps.

Note that I tried changing each separate rules to get the expected result, once I got what I wanted, I combined them and made the CSS a bit cleaner.

```js
// Set animation duration to 1 second
var carouselDuration = function() {
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000;
}

carouselDuration();
```

```css
.carousel.vertical {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item {
    width: auto;
    /* set the animation duration to 1 second */
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.right {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.left {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 2px;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url("https://grgs.ro/1/i/sprite.png") no-repeat -528px -502px;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li.active {
    background-position: -528px -524px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=west" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! See the full screen fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/t7p4kuox/13/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: You helped an entire community. You get the bounty, in a few hours :)

Comment: If I change `transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;` to `transition: 1s ease-in-out;` a small bug appears. Why?

Comment: It's because the default transition duration in the BS codebase for carousels are set to something around this, But that's not entirely causing this. There are some class addition and removal which are updated during that time and bootstrap javascript handles that delay of adding a class and removing another.
we have our transition timing set for a value but that javascript function does not care about that, hence if we increase or decrease that value, it causes that flicker.

Comment: the way these slides work is, any slide that has gone upward, after the transition they move to the very bottom of the carousel, which is translated on `X` axis to `-100%` and `top:0` when the classes for `display: hidden;` is added, the slide gets hidden before it can complete the transition, therefore the upper portion becomes blank and a white section appears.
Unfortunately I could not find a way to control that class addition / removal delay.